# how can find positon in list String?

Tags: android

my english is not well... i have tow list like list1 =[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,x,b,a] list2=[a,d,a] 
i want compare list2 with list1 and find the fist position if it same and add this position to a list Integer; 
like this

fisrt "a" of list2 = first "a" of list1 with position 1(list1) add(1) to list Integer 
"d" of list2 = "d" of list1 with position 4(list1) add(4) to list Integer 
second "a" of list2 = second "a" of list1 with position 10(list1) add(10) to list Integer 
how can I get 1,4,10?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a list array just use the function list.getPositionOf(a) for list1 and list 2. This will return an integer that you can use to compare the positions.

Comment: i thing my english is bad so u don't understand me. u see in 2 list i have tow "a", i want to get position the first "a" in list1 and then get position "d" and then get position the second "a" in list1